# `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` in vuejs when data fetch from api

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

I'm using  in bootstrapvue, I have an API that data coming from it, please see codes below, I will explain more:

```
      <b-pagination
        v-model="currentPage"
        :total-rows="rows"
        :per-page="perPage"
        aria-controls="itemList"
        align="center"
      ></b-pagination>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          posts: null,
          perPage: 1,
          currentPage: 1,
        }
      },
  computed: {
    rows() {
      if (this.posts.length >= 1 && this.posts.length !== null) {
        return this.posts.length
      } else {
        return false
      }
    },
    getItemForPagination() {
      return this.posts.slice(
        (this.currentPage - 1) * this.perPage,
        this.currentPage * this.perPage
      )
    },
  },
```

a bit of what I want to do: as you can see in the code above, I want to have pagination which items mix with it, I mean the number of items that have shown be under the control of pagination.
well, when I give rows computed property to `:total-rows` it returns an error, that I think because API isn't loaded on rows yet, but when writing on the template or console something like this as I did as on computed `rows`  `posts.length', everything works fine, but on` :total-rows` game me this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

I'm using nuxtjs

Comment: You should have write down what you did to debbug or/and solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize your `posts` property with an empty array :

```
    data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      perPage: 1,
      currentPage: 1,
    }
  },
```

then compare the length to 0 :

```
 if (this.posts.length >= 1 && this.posts.length !== 0) {
```

or just do :

```
 if (this.posts.length) {
```